# Jquery - Simulating click button doesn't trigger function

Tags: jquery, function, button, triggers, click

Ok,

So I have been using firebug and also some extensions I wrote to create shortcuts on website I use often. There's on thing that I don't understand why it doesn't work or why it's not possible:

Example code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="addNewRow()" id="addRow"/>
//This will add a new row to the current table.
//The function is defined by the website (not my function)
```

When using firebug:

```
jQuery("#addRow").click();
//This will simulate the button click, and will automatically add the new row.
```

When using google chrome extension:

```
jQuery("#addRow").click();
//It doesn't add the new row.
```

Why can't the extension execute the function once the button click occurs, and why firebug has no issues in running it?

Is this normal? Is this a security feature? or am I doing something wrong?

I know that I can't access existing functions in a website for security reasons, but why won't the button simulation trigger it for me?

Comment: My issue is that i can get the code to trigger the function using firebug, but I can't get it to work when using it as an extension. The jQuery selection works, but the function is never triggered. 

I believe the same issues happens if I use the extension in Firefox (using userscripts/greasymonkey)

So I can accomplish what I want in firebug, but I would rather have it in a extension so I don't have to copy and paste code all the time.

Comment: I tried running my extension in firefox using the jquery trigger option, but it did not work either.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhh i am having this same issue, and it is making me go crazy. O_O

Comment: After much reading, it seems that google extensions don't give you access to a website's existing function. That doesn't explain why it work in the debug console though.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
jQuery("#addRow").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, trigger did not work in the extension either. It worked is I just open the chrome console and add it there (just as firebug)

Comment: Are there any settings that I need to enable in the manafesto file?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Chrome are you using ? There is a new Chrome Extensions security feature that blocks inline javascript. You can read more here :
http://browserfame.com/512/chrome-extension-content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

On chrome, I would rather use WebKit's developer console rather than firebug extention.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that firebug does not work as well on chrome as it does on firefox. I was actually running firebug on firefox.